# Open TextFormField inside FloatingActionButton() Row() when pressing the button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

[image]

When tapping the blue button beside the red button to edit the to-do task, how can the TextFormField in the bottom be opened to edit the to-do task? knowing that TextFormField  is inside a row inside FloatingActionButton.

Here's my code:

TextFormField code:

```
class AddNewToDo extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewToDo({
    Key? key,
    required this.addTodo,
    this.initialTask,
    this.taskFocusNode,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String? initialTask;
  final Function addTodo;
  final FocusNode? taskFocusNode;

  @override
  State<AddNewToDo> createState() => _AddNewToDoState();
}

class _AddNewToDoState extends State<AddNewToDo> {
  final TextEditingController taskController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 35,
                  offset: Offset(0, 5),
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: size.width / 1.7,
              child: TextFormField(
                focusNode: widget.taskFocusNode,
                controller: taskController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Add a new todo item',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 17, horizontal: 20),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (taskController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                widget.addTodo(taskController.text);
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                taskController.clear();
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: const Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
  );


  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("Warning"),
    content: const Text("Please add a todo item."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );


  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}

                });
              }
            });
          },
          shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF5F56E8),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3, right: 2),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 40,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Edit button code:

```
CustomButton(
                        press: () {
                          setState(() {
                            taskFocusNode.requestFocus();
                          });
                        },
                        color: const Color(0xFF5F56E8),
                        customIcon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                        customMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                      ),
```

Hope someone can help me in this.

Comment: The textformfield at the bottom is for new entries. You will have to create another textformfield, maybe show it inside a dialog that will popup when pressing edit. You can pass the text value to the controller when clicking edit

Comment: You mean it is not possible to use the same textformfield for both add and update tasks?

Comment: well it is possible, but then you will need to add some if else statement when pressing the floatingactionbutton. You can do bool edit = true when clicking the edit button in this case, and pass the text to the controller

Comment: put in your code and i will edit it for you if you want to see an example

Comment: i need to see your list of all todo so i can see their values and how to edit them

Comment: Here's it: https://i.imgur.com/2fzeS1W.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253717/discussion-between-texv-and-ahmed-loutfy).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

First I will add a new bool variable and remove final from your controller to make it editable:

```
  bool editTodoItem = false;
  TextEditingController taskController = TextEditingController();
```

On the `CustomButton` for editing, turn the bool to true and set the controller to the name you want to edit:

```
                      CustomButton(
                        press: () {
                          setState(() {
                            taskFocusNode.requestFocus();
                            editTodoItem = true;
                            taskController.text = listOfTasks[index].nameOfTask ?? ''; //empty if null since your nameOfTask is nullable
                         
                          });
                        },
                      ),
```

Now you can change the `FloatingActionButton` conditionally:

```
            FloatingActionButton(
                child: Container(
                  ...
                  child: Icon(
                   editTodoItem ? Icons.add : Icons.edit,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (taskController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      //widget.addTodo(taskController.text);
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      taskController.clear();
                    } else if (editTodoItem) {
                      //widget.editTodo(taskController.text);
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      taskController.clear();
                      editTodoItem = false;
                    } else {}...
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try this code after return home from work. then I will accept your answer.

Comment: all good. if it didnt work i will need to see more of your code to understand how you handle your data so I can edit accordingly

Comment: Surely, I will do it.

Comment: I'm still waiting on the chat